# Is there a way to remove all the ssh keys added to ssh-agent when the user locks the system?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have a bunch of keys added to the `ssh-agent`, keys to servers, repositories, etc.

Is there a way to remove all the ssh keys added to ssh-agent when the user locks the system?

My system right now is Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 with GNOME 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [watch for the events in DBUS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock) and on lock call `ssh-add -D` to remove all keys from the agent:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in 
      *"boolean true"*) echo SCREEN_LOCKED; ssh-add -D;;
      *"boolean false"*) echo SCREEN_UNLOCKED;;  
    esac
  done
```

But you need to export the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable to this script, so it would be able to access your agent.

You can store the above into the script `clean_lock.sh`, set execute bits (`chmod u+x clean_lock.sh`) and run the script in background `./clean_lock.sh &`.

Comment: I have checked that answer.  But how to run a script on background that keeps listening to the state changed.

Comment: Oh hang on, that worked.

Comment: I tried [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298425/9503) answer as it said it was what worked of 16.04